# Working with the output from recfromcsv

Tags: matlab, numpy, python-2.7

I'm porting a Matlab script to Python. Below is an extract:

```
%// Create a list of unique trade dates
DateList = unique(AllData(:,1));

%// Loop through the dates
for DateIndex = 1:size(DateList,1)

    CalibrationDate = DateList(DateIndex);
    %// Extract the data for a single cablibration date (but all expiries)
    SubsetIndices = ismember(AllData(:,1) , DateList(DateIndex)) == 1;    
    SubsetAllExpiries = AllData(SubsetIndices, :);
```

`AllData` is an *N*-by-*6* cell matrix, the first 2 columns are dates (strings) and the other 4 are numbers. In python I will be getting this data out of a csv so something like this:

```
import numpy as np
AllData = np.recfromcsv(open("MyCSV.csv", "rb"))
```

So now if I'm not mistaken `AllData` is a numpy array of ordinary tuples. Is this is best format to have this data in? The goal will be to extract a list of unique dates from column 1, and for each date extract the rows with that date in column 1 (column one is ordered). Then for each row in column one do some maths on the numbers and date in the remaining 5 columns.

So in matlab I can get the list of dates by `unique(AllData(:,1))` and then I can get the records (rows) corresponding to that date (i.e. with that date in columns one) like this:

```
SubsetIndices = ismember(AllData(:,1) , MyDate) == 1;    
SubsetAllExpiries = AllData(SubsetIndices, :);
```

How can I best achieve the same results in Python?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To put things in context, `np.recfromcsv` is just a modified version of [`np.genfromtxt`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.io.genfromtxt.html) which outputs record arrays instead of structured arrays.

A [structured array](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.rec.html) lets you access the individual fields (here, your columns) by their names, like in `my_array["field_one"]` while a record array gives you the same *plus* the possibility to access the fields as attributes, like in `my_array.field_one`. I'm not fond of "access-as-attributes", so I usually stick to structured arrays.

For your information, structurede/record arrays are **not** arrays of tuples, but arrays of some numpy object call a `np.void`: it's a block of memory composed of as many sub-blocks you have of fields, the size of each sub-block depending on its datatype.

That said, yes, what you seem to have in mind is exactly the kind of usage for a structured array. The approach would then be:

- to take your `dates` array and filter them to find the unique elements.
- to find the indices of these unique elements, as an array of integers we'll call, say,  `matching`;
- to use `matching` to access the corresponding records (*eg*, rows of your array) using [fancy indexing](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.indexing.html), as
  `my_array[matching]`.
- to perform your computations on the records, as you want.

Note that you can keep your dates as strings or transform them into `datetime` objects using a user-defined converter, as described in the [documentation](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.io.genfromtxt.html). For example, your could transform a `YYYY-MM-DD` into a `datetime` object with a `lambda s:datetime.dateime.strptime(s,"%Y-%m-%d")`. That way, instead of having, say, a `N` array where each row (a record) consists of two dates as strings and 4 floats, you would have a `N` array where each row consists of two `datetime` objects and 4 floats.

Note the shape of your array (via `my_array.shape`), it says `(N,)`, meaning it's a 1D array, even if it looks like a 2D table with multiple columns. You can access individual fields (each "column") by using its name. For example, if we create an array consisting of one string field called `first` and one `int` field called `second`, like that:

```
x = np.array([('a',1),('b',2)], dtype=[('first',"|S10"),('second',int)])
```

you could access the `first` column with

```
>>> x['first']
array(['a', 'b'], 
      dtype='|S10')
```

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, but from what I can gather, I don't have a 'dates array', I have an array in which each element contains a np.void (that ostensibly resembles a tuple to me) of 2 dates and 4 floats. Is there some way I can get an array of a single column (but all the rows)? AllData[n] gives me the n + 1 th row, AllData[n][m] gives me the m + 1 th column of the n + 1 th row. AllData[n][:] doesn't work and AllData[n,:] is bad syntax. So how do I get access to the date array to filter it? Could you possibly suggest some code please?